# How to plot real time data with many options for plotting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, plotly

I have a system which gives data(real time) every second. I read the data using serial module. Now my task is to show plot of the data. Plot-1(real time), as I read every second and Plot-2, mean value of the data per minute. when I start the program, it should show the Plot-1(real time) i.e., second plot. I wish to have options when I click on "Minute Plot" Option, it should display Minute values for the past 24 hrs. I successfully read the data using serial. when it comes to plotting I stuck. I used FuncAnimation from animation. It beautifully shows second plot and updates every second (real time) but I am not able to create options for plotting and display minute plot. It may be simple but I am new to Python.Please help. Below is a part of the codes.

```
import serial
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os
import time
import struct
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

style.use('ggplot')

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0.5, xonxoff=False,
                rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

SData = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'hh', 'mm', 'ss', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

MData = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'hh', 'mm', 'A', 'B', 'C'])


def animate(i):
dat1 = ser.readline()
dat = dat1.decode('UTF-8')

nov = datetime.now()

date = nov.strftime('%b') + nov.strftime('%d') + nov.strftime('%y')

file = date + '.sss'

dat2 = [[nov.replace(microsecond=0), nov.strftime('%H'), nov.strftime('%M'), nov.strftime('%S'),
         round(float(dat[1:8]), 1),
         round(float(dat[8:15]), 1), round(float(dat[15:22]), 1)]]


Data = pd.concat([SData, pd.DataFrame(dat2, columns=['Time', 'hh', 'mm', 'ss', 'A', 'B', 'C'])], ignore_index=True)

// / Codes
for calculating mean and write to a file // /

p1.plot(Data.index, Data.A, color='blue')
p1.set_xlim([datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=0.5), datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)])

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')
label = Tk.Label(root, text="Realtime Animated Graphs").place(x=500, y=10)
Button1 = Tk.Button(root, text='Minute Plot')
Button1.place(x=500, y=860)
# graph 1
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(12, 8), linewidth=10.0, tight_layout=True)

p1 = fig.add_subplot(313)
p1.set_xlim([datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=0.5), datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)])
p1.set_ylim([0, 10])

p2 = fig.add_subplot(312, sharex=p1)
plt.setp(p2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
p2.set_ylim([0, 10])

p3 = fig.add_subplot(311, sharex=p1)
plt.setp(p3.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
p3.set_ylim([0, 10])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)

canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=10, y=50)
canvas.draw()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=False)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist a list of data for every second on your X axis.

Then, when you click on some "minute" button, you only plot every 60th element of that list.

Alternatively, store data in something like Prometheus and use Grafana to visualize rather than strictly depend on Python frameworks, then Grafana has different options to handle time granularity and ranges